# I want to find the maximum frequency of a common digit in a consecutive subset of integer array

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic

The partial digit subsequence of an array A is a subsequence of integers in which each consecutive integers have at least 1 digit in common

I keep a dictionary with 0 to 9 characters and the count of each subsequent characters. then i loop through all values in integer array and take each digit and check my dictionary for the count of that digit.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<char, int> dct = new Dictionary<char, int>
    {
        { '0', 0 },
        { '1', 0 },
        { '2', 0 },
        { '3', 0 },
        { '4', 0 },
        { '5', 0 },
        { '6', 0 },
        { '7', 0 },
        { '8', 0 },
        { '9', 0 }
    };

    string[] arr = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        string str = string.Join("", arr[i].Distinct());
        for (int j = 0; j < str.Length; j++)
        {
            int count = dct[str[j]];
            if (count == i || (i > 0 && arr[i - 1].Contains(str[j])))
            {
                count++;
                dct[str[j]] = count;
            }
            else dct[str[j]] = 1;
        }
    }
    string s = dct.Aggregate((l, r) => l.Value > r.Value ? l : r).Key.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

for e.g,
12 23 231
Answer would be 2 because it occurs 3 times

The array can contain 10^18 elements.

can someone help me with an optimal solution. This algorithm is not fit to handle large data in an array.

Comment: This looks like a fun one, and yeah there are places to speed this up for sure

Comment: So you are essentially just trying to count the occurrences of digits in the list of  numbers (which have had duplicates removed) ,

Comment: yea. calculating th occurrence of duplicate in an integer would make no sense because i want the maximum count from an array of integers

Comment: Ahh yes i see,..

Comment: Could you provide some more test cases for it. For understandin it better.

Comment: @kaarthickraman 112 ,432, 812 , 192 , 111 , 113 , 221
here answer would be 1
because it occurs at 3 4 5 6 7 index(consequent)

Comment: So its 4. 2 has 4 occurences in the first 4 values and then 1 in the last 4.  Is that it?

Comment: @amittiwari - Finding the "length of longest common digit subsequence in an integer array" is not the same as finding the digit with the highest frequency. Can you clarify what you've been asked to do?

Comment: 1 in the last 5. so the answer is 1

Comment: @Enigmativity sorry for the confusion 
i want longest common digit subsequence in an integer array

Comment: Yeah My bad.So its not about the frequency of occurrence of a digit in the whole array but its about the frequency of a common digit in a consecutive subset of array. For mine and @Enigmativity 's clarification.

Comment: @amittiwari - Which **isn't what you example suggests** - "e.g, 12 23 231 Answer would be 2 because it occurs 3 times" is the digit with the highest frequency. Can correct your question?

Comment: `12 23 231 4444 444` should be 2 also ?

Comment: @TheGeneral yes

Comment: @Enigmativity sure. I will correct my question

Comment: @amittiwari - OK, but what does "consecutive subset of integer array" mean?

Comment: @The partial digit subsequence of an array A is a subsequence of integers in which each consecutive integers have at least 1 digit in common

Comment: @amittiwari - I'm guessing English isn't your first language. The phrase "each consecutive integers have at least 1 digit in common" doesn't make a great deal of sense.

Comment: @Enigmativity dude its simple: if an integer has 123 143 451
 then 1 is common in all 3 values
4 is common in two values

Comment: @amittiwari - So, you're making groups of three?

Comment: So what if there are 2 winners, which one do you choose?

Comment: @TheGeneral the first one

Comment: Eric is right, i did miss the important part of the question, `10^18` elements, is this smells a typo? I mean i could make this a parallel file reading solution however you are going to run our of resources before you solve your problem

Comment: With 10^18 numbers, solution probably should conform to Benford's law (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law)

Answer (score 9):

All the posted answers are wrong because all of them have ignored the most important part of the question:

> The array can contain 10^18 elements.

This array is being read *from disk*? Supposing each element is two bytes, that's two million terabyte drives just for the array.  **I don't think that's going to fit into memory.**  You'll have to go with a streaming solution.

How long will the streaming solution take?  If you can process a billion array items a second, which seems within reason, your program will take 32 years to execute.

Your requirements are not realistic, and so the problem cannot feasibly be solved with the resources of a single person.  You'll need the resources of a large corporation or nation to attack this problem, and you'll need a lot of funding for hardware acquisition and management.

The linear algorithm is trivial; it's the size of the data that is the entire problem. Start building your data center somewhere with cheap power and friendly tax laws, because you are going to be importing a lot of disks.

Comment: Yes, 10^18 is a big number. I assumed he wants an algorithm that could handle *up to* that number. And you're right, the linear algorithm that requires minimal memory is trivial.

Comment: @JimMischel: Right, the algorithm is not the problem at all.  The question is poorly stated; if the intention was to say "a solution constant in memory burden and linear in time with the size of the input" then that's the question that should have been posed. I don't know where this ten to the 18 figure comes from.

Comment: @EricLippert 10^18 is about 2^60. Well, at least it's marginally better than "I want to enumerate all the GUIDs, all of them".

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to go through the array elements one by one, you can simply merge the entire string array into 1 string and go through the characters

12 23 231 -> "1223231" , loop through and count it.

It should be fast enough O(n) and require only 10 entries in your dictionary. How "fast" do you exactly need ?

Comment: suppose the array is 21 32 132 then merging won't help right?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use arrays, I'm not sure if u must use arrays, if not, check this solution.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<char> numbers = new List<char>();
        Dictionary<char, int> dct = new Dictionary<char, int>()
        {
            { '0',0 },
            { '1',0 },
            { '2',0 },
            { '3',0 },
            { '4',0 },
            { '5',0 },
            { '6',0 },
            { '7',0 },
            { '8',0 },
            { '9',0 },
        };

        string option;

        do
        {
            Console.Write("Enter number: ");
            string number = Console.ReadLine();
            numbers.AddRange(number);

            Console.Write("Enter 'X' if u want to finish work: ");
            option = Console.ReadLine();

        } while (option.ToLower() != "x");

        foreach(char c in numbers)
        {
            if(dct.ContainsKey(c))
            {
                dct[c]++;
            }
        }

        foreach(var keyValue in dct)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Char {keyValue.Key} was used {keyValue.Value} times");
        }

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

Comment: it wont pass the test case if the array is
112 221 232 251 113 114
It will give 1 as output because it occurs 5 times
but correct answer is 2 which occur four times but in a sequence

Comment: I'm not really following, can u explain me what exactly are u trying to get? I thought u want number of digit usage.

Comment: 12 23 231 4444 444 answer will be 2
because 2 is there in 0 1 2 indexes
which makes it longest common subsequence

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you three versions.

Basically, I just loaded up a list of random ints as string, the scale is how many, and run it on Core and Framework to see. Each test was run 10 times and averaged.

**Mine1**

Uses Distinct

```
public unsafe class Mine : Benchmark<List<string>, char>
{
   protected override char InternalRun()
   {
      var result = new int[10];
      var asd = Input.Select(x => new string(x.Distinct().ToArray())).ToList();
      var raw = string.Join("", asd);

      fixed (char* pInput = raw)
      {
         var len = pInput + raw.Length;
         for (var p = pInput; p < len; p++)
         {
            result[*p - 48]++;
         }
      }

      return (char)(result.ToList().IndexOf(result.Max()) + '0');
   }
}
```

**Mine2**

Basically this uses a second array to work things out

```
public unsafe class Mine2 : Benchmark<List<string>, char>
{
   protected override char InternalRun()
   {
      var result = new int[10];
      var current = new int[10];
      var raw = string.Join(" ", Input);

      fixed (char* pInput = raw)
      {
         var len = pInput + raw.Length;
         for (var p = pInput; p < len; p++)
            if (*p != ' ')
               current[*p - 48] = 1;
            else
               for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
               {
                  result[i] += current[i];
                  current[i] = 0;
               }
 
      }

      return (char)(result.ToList().IndexOf(result.Max()) + '0');
   }
}
```

**Mine3**

No Joins or string allocation

```
public unsafe class Mine3 : Benchmark<List<string>, char>
{
   protected override char InternalRun()
   {
      var result = new int[10];

      foreach (var item in Input)
         fixed (char* pInput = item)
         {
            var current = new int[10];
            var len = pInput + item.Length;

            for (var p = pInput; p < len; p++)
               current[*p - 48] = 1;

            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
               result[i] += current[i];
               current[i] = 0;
            }
         }
         

      return (char)(result.ToList().IndexOf(result.Max()) + '0');
   }
}
```

#Results .Net Framework 4.7.1

```
Mode            : Release
Test Framework  : .Net Framework 4.7.1
Benchmarks runs : 10 times (averaged)

Scale : 10,000
Name     |   Average |   Fastest | StDv |     Cycles | Pass |        Gain
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mine3    |  0.533 ms |  0.431 ms | 0.10 |  1,751,372 | Base |      0.00 %
Mine2    |  0.994 ms |  0.773 ms | 0.38 |  3,100,896 | Yes  |    -86.63 %
Mine     |  8.122 ms |  7.012 ms | 1.29 | 27,480,083 | Yes  | -1,424.78 %
Original | 20.729 ms | 16.044 ms | 4.56 | 65,316,558 | No   | -3,791.47 %


Scale : 100,000
Name     |    Average |    Fastest |  StDv |      Cycles | Pass |        Gain
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mine3    |   4.766 ms |   4.475 ms |  0.34 |  16,140,716 | Base |      0.00 %
Mine2    |   8.424 ms |   7.890 ms |  0.33 |  28,577,416 | Yes  |    -76.76 %
Mine     |  96.650 ms |  93.066 ms |  3.35 | 327,615,266 | Yes  | -1,927.94 %
Original | 163.342 ms | 154.070 ms | 12.61 | 550,038,934 | No   | -3,327.32 %


Scale : 1,000,000
Name     |      Average |      Fastest |  StDv |        Cycles | Pass |        Gain
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mine3    |    49.827 ms |    48.600 ms |  1.19 |   169,162,589 | Base |      0.00 %
Mine2    |   106.334 ms |    97.641 ms |  6.53 |   359,773,719 | Yes  |   -113.41 %
Mine     | 1,051.600 ms | 1,000.731 ms | 35.75 | 3,511,515,189 | Yes  | -2,010.51 %
Original | 1,640.385 ms | 1,588.431 ms | 65.50 | 5,538,915,638 | No   | -3,192.18 %
```

#Results .Net Core 2.0

```
Mode            : Release
Test Framework  : Core 2.0
Benchmarks runs : 10 times (averaged)

Scale : 10,000
Name     |   Average |   Fastest | StDv |     Cycles | Pass |        Gain
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mine3    |  0.476 ms |  0.353 ms | 0.12 |  1,545,995 | Base |      0.00 %
Mine2    |  0.554 ms |  0.551 ms | 0.00 |  1,883,570 | Yes  |    -16.23 %
Mine     |  7.585 ms |  5.875 ms | 1.27 | 25,580,339 | Yes  | -1,492.28 %
Original | 21.380 ms | 16.263 ms | 6.46 | 65,741,909 | No   | -4,388.14 %


Scale : 100,000
Name     |    Average |    Fastest |  StDv |      Cycles | Pass |        Gain
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mine3    |   3.946 ms |   3.685 ms |  0.25 |  13,409,181 | Base |      0.00 %
Mine2    |   6.203 ms |   5.796 ms |  0.33 |  21,042,340 | Yes  |    -57.21 %
Mine     |  72.975 ms |  68.599 ms |  4.13 | 246,471,960 | Yes  | -1,749.41 %
Original | 161.400 ms | 145.664 ms | 19.37 | 544,703,761 | Yes  | -3,990.40 %


Scale : 1,000,000
Name     |      Average |      Fastest |  StDv |        Cycles | Pass |        Gain
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mine3    |    41.036 ms |    38.928 ms |  2.47 |   139,045,736 | Base |      0.00 %
Mine2    |    71.283 ms |    68.777 ms |  2.49 |   241,525,269 | Yes  |    -73.71 %
Mine     |   749.250 ms |   720.809 ms | 27.79 | 2,479,171,863 | Yes  | -1,725.84 %
Original | 1,517.240 ms | 1,477.321 ms | 48.94 | 5,142,422,700 | No   | -3,597.35 %
```

#Summary

String allocation, join, and distinct suck for performance. If you need more performance you could probably break the list up into work loads and smash this in parallel.

Comment: Does your code produce the correct results? Given the input `123 196 32 475 38`, the answer should be `1`, because it's the digit that occurs most often in consecutive numbers. It looks like your code would return `3`, because it's the digit that occurs most often.

Comment: @JimMischel you are right mine will return the most common number not consecutive

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not an efficient solution but this will work.

```
public class Program
{
    public static int arrLength = 0;
    public static string[] arr;
    public static Dictionary<char, int> dct = new Dictionary<char, int>();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dct.Add('0', 0);
        dct.Add('1', 0);
        dct.Add('2', 0);
        dct.Add('3', 0);
        dct.Add('4', 0);
        dct.Add('5', 0);
        dct.Add('6', 0);
        dct.Add('7', 0);
        dct.Add('8', 0);
        dct.Add('9', 0);

        arr = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        arrLength = arr.Length;
        foreach (string str in arr)
        {
            char[] ch = str.ToCharArray();
            ch = ch.Distinct<char>().ToArray();
            foreach (char c in ch)
            {
                Exists(c, Array.IndexOf(arr, str));
            }
        }

        int val = dct.Values.Max();
        foreach(KeyValuePair<char,int> v in dct.Where(x => x.Value == val))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Common digit {0} with frequency {1} ",v.Key,v.Value+1);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static bool Exists(char c, int pos)
    {
        int count = 0;
        if (pos == arrLength - 1)
            return false;

        for (int i = pos; i < arrLength - 1; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i + 1].ToCharArray().Contains(c))
            {
                count++;
                if (count > dct[c])
                    dct[c] = count;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As somebody else pointed out, if you have 10^18 numbers then this is going to be a lot more data than you can fit into memory. So you need a streaming solution. You also don't want to spend a lot of time on memory allocation or converting strings to character arrays, calling functions to de-duplicate digits, etc. Ideally, you need a solution that looks at each character once.

The memory requirement of the program below is very small: just two small arrays of long integers.

The algorithm I developed maintains two arrays of counts per digit. One is the maximum number of consecutive occurrences of a digit, and the other is the most recent count of consecutive occurrences.

The code itself reads the file character-by-character, accumulating digits until it encounters a character that is not a digit, then it updates the current counts array for each digit encountered. If the current count exceeds the maximum count, then the max count for that digit is updated. If a digit doesn't appear in a number, then its current count is reset to 0.

The occurrence of individual digits in a number is maintained by setting bits in the `digits` variable. That way, a number like 1221 will not count the digits twice.

```
using (var input = File.OpenText("filename"))
{
    var maxCounts = new long[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    var latestCounts = new long[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    char prevChar = ' ';

    word digits = 0;
    while (!input.EndOfStream)
    {
        var c = input.Read();

        // If the character is a digit, set the corresponding bit
        if (char.IsDigit(c))
        {
            digits |= (1 << (c-'0'));
            prevChar = c;
            continue;
        }

        // test here to prevent resetting counts when there are multiple non-digit
        // characters between numbers.
        if (!char.IsDigit(prevChar))
        {
            continue;
        }
        prevChar = c;

        // digits has a bit set for every digit
        // that occurred in the number.
        // Update the counts arrays.

        // For each of the first 10 bits, update the corresponding count.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            if ((digits & 1) == 1)
            {
                ++latestCounts[i];
                if (latestCounts[i] > maxCounts[i])
                {
                    maxCounts[i] = latestCounts[i];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                latestCounts[i] = 0;
            }
            // Shift the next bit into place.
            digits >> 1;
        }
        digits = 0;
    }
}
```

This code minimizes the processing required, but the program's running time will be dominated by the speed at which you can read the file. There are optimizations you can make to increase the input speed, but ultimately you're limited to your system's data transfer speed.